# How to get list of all objects associated with a foreign key in Django

Tags: python, django

Not super experienced with Django so I apologize if this is trivial. Say I had a category instance and I wanted to get access to all of the content objects that I have previously added to my foreign key. How would I do so?

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=200, default=uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    phoneNumber=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    logo=models.CharField(max_length=100000) # storing this as base 64 encoded
    location=models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Category(models.Model):
    categoryName=models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    associatedOrganizations=models.ForeignKey(Organization,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='associatedOrgs',null=True,blank=True)
    associatedContent=models.ForeignKey(Content, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='associatedContent',null=True,blank=True)
    associatedMeetingNotices=models.ForeignKey(MeetingNotice,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='associatedMeetingNotices',null=True,blank=True)
```

For example:
say I had the following

```
healthcareCategory=models.Category.objects.get(pk="healthcare")
```

and I wanted to access all Organizations related to healthcare, what should I do?

This?

```
healthcareCategory.associatedOrganizations.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @AMG is correct.  If you had *not* defined a related_name for associatedOrganizations you could simply do

```py
organizations = Organization.objects.filter(category__pk='healthcare')
```

But I think there is another issue.  Am I correct in saying that an Organization can have *only one* Category, but a Category can have *many* Organizations?

If so, then I think the ForeignKey in your model is in the wrong place.

```py
class Organization(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=200, default=uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    phoneNumber=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    logo=models.CharField(max_length=100000) # storing this as base 64 encoded
    location=models.CharField(max_length=200)

    # The ForeignKey should be here:
    category = ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Category(models.Model):
    categoryName=models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    
    # remove this
    # associatedOrganizations=models.ForeignKey(Organization,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='associatedOrgs',null=True,blank=True)

    ...
```

The ForeignKey is a `ManyToOneField` so you place it in the model that will be the many, and you link it to the model that will be the one.

Now you can find all organizations within the healthcare category like this:

```py
organizations = Organization.objects.filter(category='healthcare')
```

Answer (score 2):

You are close. You may want to change that related name from `associatedOrgs` to be `associatedorgs` to follow more closely to the [django coding style](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/). [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) on this has a few examples.

```
healthcare_category = Category.objects.get(pk="healthcare")
organizations = healthcare_category.associatedorgs.all()
```